# model.fit taking 30 minutes to set-up but only 3ms to run an epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

## System information

- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): Yes
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Linux ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue happens on mobile device: N/A
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): via pip3
- TensorFlow version (use command below): v2.2.0-rc4-8-g2b96f3662b 2.2.0
- Python version: 3.8.2
- Bazel version (if compiling from source): N/A
- GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): N/A
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 10.1
- GPU model and memory: GeForce RTX 2070 8gb
- Describe the current behavior:

When running model.fit it takes around 30 minutes each epoch before the progress bar shows up. the actual step then takes around 3ms to complete. is there any way to speed this up? and what is happening during these 30 minutes? I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run the code.

## code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

batch_size = 1024

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical, plot_model
dataset_controller = pd.read_csv("data_template_braincap.csv")
randomint = round((len(dataset_controller.index) * 0.8))
randomint2 = round(len(dataset_controller.index) - randomint)
train=dataset_controller.head(randomint)
test=dataset_controller.tail(randomint2)
X_train = train.drop(['actual time', 'timestamp bci', 'timestamp controller', 'left stick x:', 'left stick y:', 'right stick x:', 'right stick y:', 'a:', 'b:', 'x:', 'y:', 'right trigger:'], axis = 1)
y_train = train['a:']
X_test = test.drop(['actual time', 'timestamp bci', 'timestamp controller', 'left stick x:', 'left stick y:', 'right stick x:', 'right stick y:', 'a:', 'b:', 'x:', 'y:', 'right trigger:'], axis = 1)
y_test = test['a:']


y_train = y_train.head(len(y_train)-256)

y_train = y_train.values.reshape((1, len(y_train), 1))
X_train = X_train.shift(periods=-256, fill_value=0)
X_train = X_train.head(len(X_train)-256)
X_train = X_train.values.reshape((1, len(X_train), 19))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add((layers.SimpleRNN(64, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=2048)
```

the dataset has 31 columns and 339972 rows.
the first 5 rows look like this:

```
0,44295.68,15337.95,-187500.02,-187500.02,-56777.86,-41605.74,-73884.49,-78516.45,-187500.02,6256.72,-187500.02,-64932.48,-53366.2,-59987.21,-187500.02,-24877.74,0.0,0.0,0.0,14:08:15.156,1591358895156,1591358895164,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,43882.2,14582.72,-187500.02,-187500.02,-57811.38,-43702.24,-74505.63,-79345.52,-187500.02,-17205.57,-187500.02,-62077.83,-52917.82,-57371.2,-187500.02,-32231.13,0.02,0.972,0.168,14:08:15.214,1591358895214,1591358895172,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,44356.3,15663.66,-187500.02,-187500.02,-55410.51,-41974.36,-72097.02,-76903.34,-187500.02,-2991.58,-187500.02,-63242.92,-52042.46,-58320.08,-187500.02,-29449.72,0.0,0.0,0.0,14:08:15.214,1591358895214,1591358895180,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,43967.04,14665.94,-187500.02,-187500.02,-58229.8,-42705.06,-75319.74,-80001.02,-187500.02,-3170.95,-187500.02,-64025.45,-53815.11,-59228.72,-187500.02,-26920.17,0.0,0.0,0.0,14:08:15.214,1591358895214,1591358895188,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4,44212.8,15311.93,-187500.02,-187500.02,-55950.53,-43095.84,-72422.33,-77356.32,-187500.02,-15505.09,-187500.02,-61992.98,-51984.52,-57185.35,-187500.02,-33186.15,0.0,0.0,0.0,14:08:15.214,1591358895214,1591358895196,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Keras output during model.fit:

```
Epoch 1/500
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3895
Epoch 2/500
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 232.1620
Epoch 3/500
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 20.5877
Epoch 4/500
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 51.7856
```

Comment: Can you add the output of keras to your question? Where do the 3 ms figure came from?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Added it to the main post.